# Which RubyMine generated files should I commit?

Tags: version-control, rubymine

RubyMine generates some files in the .idea directory. In one of my projects I see:

- *project_name*.iml
- encodings.xml
- misc.xml
- modules.xml
- vcs.xml
- workspace.xml

Which should I commit to the version control system and which shouldn't?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As stated on http://www.jetbrains.net/devnet/docs/DOC-1192:

> RubyMine stores project configuration
>   files under .idea directory that is
>   auto-created in project root folder.
>
> For better collaboration between
>   project team you should put under the
>   version control all the files under
>   .idea  directory in the project root
>   except the workspace.xml and 
>   tasks.xml files which store user
>   specific settings.

Comment: Eugene, you may want to say that you work at JetBrains in your bio, it'd make your answers more credible ;)

Answer (score 3):

For RubyMine, it may be preferable not to share the project files at all, because much more of the stuff is configured automatically based on your local settings (like the gems that you have installed locally).